# Spring + Hibernate auditing (no Spring Data)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

I have joined a project that was built for a year with Spring and Hibernate with Agile methodology and it didn't use Spring Data and has its own user class (not descendent of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` ).

Auditing came up as a new feauture to be implemented. (It's not enough to log the what controllers were called, we have to log every DB field's change, and which user did it. One controller can cause a lot of DB fields to change.) What are my options?

I have been looking at Javers, Envers and Audit4j. Javers requires Spring Data, so it's out. Envers' only requirement is Hibernate, which is statisfied, but I still don't see how the User object will be passed to it from the controller (the User's auth token is in the request object).

Comment: JaVers does not requires Spring at all, I've been able to configure it just with Hibernate.

Comment: can you update on what have you chose and how is it so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Envers only gives you versioning (what have happened to an object at what time), but it doesn't help you figuring out who did the change.

A simple solution to the who-part is to create two new fields on all objects that shall be audited (i.e. in a base class such as AbstractAuditableEntity): `User createdBy;` and `User lastModifiedBy;`. Add two methods (I'm assuming you're using Spring Security here):

```
@PrePersist
protected void setCreatedBy() {createdBy = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();}

@PreUpdate
protected void setCreatedBy() {lastModifiedBy = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();}
```

Comment: Hibernate supports custom `RevisionEntity` where you can store such information with each revision.

Comment: I don't understand Spring Security yet. It seems weird to me that I can get a principal through calling a static objects method instead of getting a SecurityContext through a method parameter. Does Spring do some kind of hidden locking on SecurityContext per http session?

Comment: @zslevi normally it uses a ThreadLocal which is populated in a ServletFilter